# Reading int from .txt , save it to vector and then save to output file

Tags: c++, vector, stream, text-files, fstream

I've written a mysterious program that it suppose to open and read this .txt

> `> krol.txt

```
3 7
3 13
2 4
3 1
```

and then save it to vector, do some crazy operation with some algorithms, save it to another vector and stream it into file. But crazy thing are going after running .exe. it doesn't show anything, nothing happens. No errors during compiling and... yeah. idk what went wrong.
got any idea about what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int nwd (int a,int b);
int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("krol.txt");
    if (!fin) cout << "WTF" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    vector<int> tab;
    int i=0;
    int n=0;
    while (fin>> i){
        tab.push_back(i);
    }
    fin.close();
    vector<int> result;
    bool right=false;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("save.txt");
    i=0;
    result.at(0)=tab.at(0);
    while(result.at(i)!=1){
        if (right){
            result.push_back(tab.at(i+2));
        }
        else if (nwd(result.at(i),tab.at(i+2))==1) result.push_back(tab.at(i+2));
        else {
            result.push_back(tab.at(i+1)); right=true;
        }
        outFile << result.at(i) << " " ;
        i++;
    }
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
int nwd(int a,int b){
    while (a!=b){
        a>b ? a-=b : b-=a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Check that the file is "ok" after `open` - `if (!fin) cout << "file not opened ok" << endl;` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. You need to change the code while(result.at(i)!=1){ 
to this one while(tab.at(i)!=1){. That's just a little bug.

Comment: What you need to do in the while loop is to traverse the numbers in the tab, don't you?

Comment: no, its finding way from left topcorner to down right corner. Only can move when function ==1

Comment: I guess the nwd is used to compute the greast common divisor of arguments a and b, is it? But how can you guarantee that the second while loop can exit in any condiction, especially in the specific one. Because it never goes backwards, so if it misses the right number, it can never meet it again. Just think it.

Comment: Well, the file is filled with always correct way. there sin't possibility to be wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` vector is empty, therefore this

```
while(result.at(i)!=1){
```

Will throw `out_of_range` exception and cause your program to terminate.

Comment: result.at(0)=tab.at(0);I've added it to code before while loop but it still kinda buggy